# Highcharts spacing issue on xAxis in column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I create a simple column chart with at least 2 datapoints there is annoying spacing as you can see in the jsfiddle. The width of the spacing scales with the smallest distance between two datapoints. I can't find any other options besides the one I've already set (min, max, minRange) to prevent the spacing.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: { 
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 23,
        minRange: 23
    },      
    series: [{
        data:[[0,10], [23,10]]
    }]
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f5JUU/2/ (Big spacing)
http://jsfiddle.net/f5JUU/3/ (No spacing. This is how the other Jsfiddle should look like too...)

Comment: so.. what you want.. be clear with your question.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough... I want to get rid of the auto spacing as you see it in the first jsfiddle, so that it always looks like in the second jsfiddle.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how it should looks like, because when you get rid of spacign between columns what is the purpose of using min/max 1/23 insead of i.e from 1 to 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you mean the spacing between the points, or the size of the points.

if the size, use pointRange:

http://jsfiddle.net/f5JUU/4/

```
pointRange:1
```

If you want the data to be like your 'big spacing' example, but the chart to look like your 'small spacing' example, then you just need to make your x axis max value much larger.

http://jsfiddle.net/f5JUU/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use groupPadding / pointPadding / pointWidth parameters and adapt columns correct with your expectations.

All parametsers are documented here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts